# Limit arcgis .net SDK 100.1 zoom levels

Tags: c#, maps, arcgis, arcgis-runtime-net

I'm using the ArcGIS Runtime SDK 100.1.0 for .NET. I have a mobile map package (.mmpk) vector map and want to limit the maximum and minimum zoom in the MapView. I tried to track the MapScale property and set it:

```
((INotifyPropertyChanged)MyMapView).PropertyChanged += (sender, args) =>
    {
        args.PropertyName;
        var s = MyMapView.MapScale;
        if(s < 500)
            MyMapView.SetViewpointScaleAsync(700);
        if (s > 16500000)
            MyMapView.SetViewpointScaleAsync(16500000);
    };
```

This works, but map jerks at low/high zoom levels because it tries to smooth zoom and I can't figure out how to stop the active zooming task. What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The easy way

If you just want to set a minimum scale and a maximum scale, the [`Map` class](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/latest/wpf/api-reference//html/T_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Mapping_Map.htm) has [`MinScale`](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/latest/wpf/api-reference//html/P_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Mapping_Map_MinScale.htm) and [`MaxScale`](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/latest/wpf/api-reference//html/P_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Mapping_Map_MaxScale.htm) properties. Replace your code with the following:

```
MyMapView.Map.MaxScale = 700;
MyMapView.Map.MinScale = 16500000;
```

## The hard way

*You probably don't need this! Use the easy way listed above unless you have a good reason to do something more complicated!*

If instead for some reason you really want to track scale changes and then change the scale yourself, you should do it in a different way. Currently you're listening for `PropertyChanged`, which is way too broad. One effect is that when the scale changes, your event handler runs, which performs an **asynchronous** zoom, which generates a scale change *before it's finished*, which calls your event handler, which performs an **asynchronous** zoom, which generates a scale change *before it's finished*, which calls your event handler, which...I could go on and on. Literally. And so will your program, unless you make some changes.

Here's one way to do it:

```
// Save a variable so you can invoke the EventHandler elsewhere
EventHandler navigationCompletedHandler = (sender, args) =>
{
    var s = MyMapView.MapScale;
    if (s < 500)
        MyMapView.SetViewpointScaleAsync(700);
    if (s > 16500000)
        MyMapView.SetViewpointScaleAsync(16500000);
};
MyMapView.NavigationCompleted += navigationCompletedHandler;

// Invoke the above handler one time when the map first loads
EventHandler firstViewpointChangeHandler = null;
firstViewpointChangeHandler = (sender, args) =>
{
    if (!double.IsNaN(MyMapView.MapScale))
    {
        MyMapView.ViewpointChanged -= firstViewpointChangeHandler;
        navigationCompletedHandler.Invoke(null, null);
    }
};
MyMapView.ViewpointChanged += firstViewpointChangeHandler;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the zoom levels to whatever intervals you want in ArcMap for your map file, when you build your map package / publish it to a service ArcMap seems to honour it (does for me at least).

Map Scale Drop Down -> Customize This List -> Standard Scales -> Tick the box "Only display these scales when zooming"

Saves having to write a custom mapscale event handler.